# import large MySQL Database - PHPMyAdmin error

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

Trying to import a very large database file.
Windows Apache PhpMyAdmin.

```
USE test;
source somefil.sql;
```

I get a syntax error:
"You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'source somefil.sql' at line 1 "

Comment: That command is for mysql's command line client, not for phpmyadmin, no matter how many times you paste that link into this topic. It is not available in phpmyadmin, hence the syntax error message. Phpmyadmin is not really suitable for importing large files into mysql.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Actually source command is used from command prompt so Use below steps-

Go to command prompt-

connect mysql

now use below command-

```
source d:/backup/somefil.sql;
```

Comment: I have tried this exactly - and same as the suggestions here:
 source file_name, \. file_name

Read the named file and executes the statements contained therein. On Windows, you can specify path name separators as / or \\.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-commands.html
Still produces the "you have an error" I am copy and pasting exact syntax - the path is correct - and there is no error about the path

Comment: don't use ";" at the end and try.

Comment: what is your folder name

Comment: the file I want to import is exactly C:/Apache24/htdocs/myfolder/somefil.sql

Comment: folder where .sql file exist for which you mention dummy name as myfolder.

Comment: @Kreeverp # symbol comments that line out, this is why you do not get any error message, nor are the contents executed.

Answer (score 1):

There is no such command in mysql server as `source`. This command is specific to mysql own command line client, which is also named mysql, therefore it is not available in phpmyadmin.

Copy-paste the contents of the sql file into the command window of phpmyadmin and execute its contents directly from there. You may have to increase the php max execution time parameter, if the import file is truly big.

However, I would use the command line client to execute a really big sql file because phpmyadmin is not suitable for that.

Comment: That's a command line interface command, not a general mysql command. That is not going to work in phpmyadmin. Pls read the documentation more carefully!

Comment: what is your folder name

Comment: This is why I suggested you to use the command line interface to execute a large sql file. Phpmyadmin is not designed to do this.

Comment: shadow  - so you are saying - it is a command - but not a PhpMyAdmin command. It is a command that can only be run from the command prompt? If that is so - why not post that as your answer and I will credit you for the answer.

Comment: That is what I wrote in my answer above: source is not a mysql command. What you linked says mysql command, but mysql in that context refers to the command line client named mysql. Perhaps the developers should have chosen a different name for their client to avoid ambiguity, but we cannot do anything about it at the moment.

Comment: your answer says "There is no such command as 'source' in MySQL" Which is not true - source is just not used in PhpMyAdmin. If you want to edit your answer to be clear that it is a command - but not used in PhpMyAdmin - I can credit you with the answer.

Comment: also - it is not possible to baste the contents of a 1 g file into the PHPMySQL command line. If you want to clean up your answer

Comment: Mysql's own command line client. It is installed alongside mysql server.

Answer (score 0):

to restor backup of my datebase I use command like that
  from your os command promt :

> > mysql -u youruser -p yourdatabasename < yourfilewithfullpath.sql

Comment: You send command,mentioned above, from operating system command line prompt NOT FROM MySQL command line prompt,do you?

Comment: No - I do not know which command prompt software to use. Can you recommend which software to I execute these commands from?

Comment: I'm not talking about any software, I'm talking about OS shell. Execute command, mentioned above, from the OS shell,could you?:)

Comment: "OS Shell" = "command line interface" Do you mean MS-DOS? application? "software" Is a CLI not a piece of software?

Comment: No, I don't mean mysql client (myslq.exe). I mean windows command line cmd.exe(dos,http://www.computerhope.com/issues/chusedos.htm), for example, or ubuntu bash prompt.